# 'No module named' in locust

Tags: python, locust

When I try to run my load test in locust I import another module in my case I import pyquery I receve error message:

```
[2018-05-07 16:31:49,744] Mac.local/ERROR/stderr: imported = __import__(os.path.splitext(locustfile)[0])
[2018-05-07 16:31:49,744] Mac.local/ERROR/stderr:
[2018-05-07 16:31:49,744] Mac.local/ERROR/stderr: File "load_tests/web/login/locustfile.py", line 2, in <module>
[2018-05-07 16:31:49,745] Mac.local/ERROR/stderr:
[2018-05-07 16:31:49,745] Mac.local/ERROR/stderr: import pyquery
[2018-05-07 16:31:49,745] Mac.local/ERROR/stderr:
[2018-05-07 16:31:49,745] Mac.local/ERROR/stderr: ModuleNotFoundError
[2018-05-07 16:31:49,745] Mac.local/ERROR/stderr: :
[2018-05-07 16:31:49,745] Mac.local/ERROR/stderr: No module named 'pyquery'
```

But I know that I have this module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the path to your lib in your `PYTHONPATH`

You can do it as an environment setting, or you can do it through your script using:

```
sys.path.append_relative(relativ_path_to_your_lib)
```